# Окно 'ttt' открывается до его вызова

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
bbb = Tk()
def aaa():
    ttt = Toplevel()
    ttt.title('ttt')
men = Menu()
ff = Menu(tearoff=0)
men.add_cascade(label='kkk', menu=ff)
ff.add_command(label='ooo', command=aaa())
```

Прошу объяснить причину данного явления.

Comment: Запускаю ваш код и у меня ничего не появилось

Answer (score 1):

У вас меню (men) не привязано к основному окну(bbb). Как я понял, вы хотите, чтобы в основном окне по нажатии на кнопку 'ooo' вызывалось дочернее окно, так? Тогда подойдет этот код:

```
from tkinter import *
bbb = Tk()
def aaa():
    ttt = Toplevel()
    ttt.title('ttt')
men = Menu(bbb)
bbb.config(menu=men)
men.add_cascade(label='kkk', menu=bbb)
men.add_command(label='ooo', command=aaa)
```

Comment: можно упомянуть: если `f` это функция, то `f()` вызывает эту функцию в Питоне. Поэтому `command=aaa()` сразу вызывает функцию aaa в коде в вопросе.